# Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have drawn a quadratic bezier curve using a path in SVG. I had got the required output but its showing console error,

Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 10 20 Q 15 8 15 20 Z M 15 20 Q 20 23 20 13 0  Z".

Here is my code snippet:

```
<svg>
<path fill="#C4C24A" stroke-width="1" stroke="#C4C24A" opacity="1" d="M 10 20 Q 15 8 15 20 Z M 15 20 Q 20 23 20 13 0  Z" >
</path>
</svg>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/n5rgx56r/1/)

Anyone help me on resolving this issue.

Thanks, Dharani.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your path twice with Z, thus, adding two different paths to one single tag.

Use different path tags or eliminate one of your Zs from the d attribute

Comment: I have eliminated one of the Z(closing path), but still getting the same error. Also tried with different path tags,  but i was not able resolve the issue. Kindly suggest me any other ways to resolve this issue .

Comment: You have also a Q with 4 parameters and another Q with 5 parameters... check the correctness of your d attribute on documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d